# The Effect of SOC on Charge Transfer

Tags: spin-orbit-coupling

Spin-orbit coupling (SOC) is a fundamental quantum mechanical phenomenon that arises due to the interaction between the spin of an electron and its orbital motion around an atomic nucleus. It is a relativistic effect that becomes more prominent as the atomic number of the atom increases.

As a result of spin-orbit coupling, the energy levels of electrons in atoms are split into sublevels with different total angular momentum values. This splitting is known as the fine structure. The energy difference between these sublevels depends on the magnitude of the spin-orbit coupling and the specific electronic configuration of the atom.

I would like to know whether SOC may have a big influence on the charge transfer process that happens between adsorbate-adsorbent. For instance, a paramagnetic gas molecule adsorbed on the surface of material that has heavy elements where SOC is supposed to be significant.